# Toggle divs with from menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am setting up a page to show/hide content by clicking on a menu item, using jquery. In each case I also hide the other divs. The following code seems sensible to me, but I guess I'm missing something because it works inconsistently. Sometimes clicking on a menu item works as expected and other times it does not. Something to do with hiding divs even when they are hidden?

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#commercial-menu-item').click(function() {
        $('#other').toggle();
        $('#intuito').hide();
        $('#pro-bono').hide();
        $('#all').hide();
    });
    $('#other-menu-item').click(function() {
        $('#other').toggle();
        $('#commercial').hide();
        $('#pro-bono').hide();
        $('#all').hide();
    });
    $('#pro-bono-menu-item').click(function() {
        $('#pro-bono').toggle();
        $('#other').hide();
        $('#commercial').hide();
        $('#all').hide();
    });
    $('#all-menu-item').click(function() {
        $('#all').toggle();
        $('#other').hide();
        $('#pro-bono').hide();
        $('#commercial').hide();
    });
});
```

This is the first real thing I've done with jquery, so it probably shows...

Comment: can you share the related html

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show your code (put it there).
Also, perhaps you could slap a 'nav' class onto each nav item (along with its ID). Make a custom click function that forces all 'nav' class items to hide and then lighting up the ID that was clicked/targeted.

Comment: Can you put a full example up on jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: Why are you toggling `#other` and hiding `#intuito` when clicking `#commercial-menu-item`, when you have an element with the ID `#commercial` ? Did you get your selectors right !

Comment: You are much better off writing a single click handler for all the buttons (with a common class on them) and driving their related items from `data-...` attributes on the options. The the logic becomes "collapse everything except the selected item and toggle the selected item".

Comment: +1 for providing code (HTML too in a JSFiddle would be preferable next time). Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are much better off writing a single click handler for all the buttons (with a common class on them) and driving their related items from data-... attributes on the options.

Then the logic becomes "collapse everything except the selected item and toggle the selected item"

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dWQaL/

A menu option would look like:

```
<a id="pro-bono-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#pro-bono">Pro bono</a>
```

Where data-item is simply a selector for the related div etc. The id's on the menu items are also no longer needed.

An example of the code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').click(function () {
        var $clicked = $(this)
        $('.menu').each(function () {
            var $menu = $(this);
            if (!$menu.is($clicked)) {
                $($menu.attr('data-item')).hide();
            }
        });
        $($clicked.attr('data-item')).toggle();
    });
});
```

This will give you more flexibility. You can easily add new options without changing the code of every button.

An added bonus is that you can style the clicked/unclicked items (e.g. by toggling a style on it), again with no duplication of code as everything goes through one function.

### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dWQaL/1/

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking: "there probably is a way to do this with out specifying each item."

Comment: Thanks for that! just wondering if we could add a nice transition in and out?

Answer (score -1):

Its a good start but I would probably use $('div').toggleClass('show');

Then you can write your css like

```
div {
    display:none;
}

div.show {
    display:block;
}
```

i'll try to write a jsfiddle for your specific solution, but give me a bit!
It should clear it up alot! Let me know if you have another question or need anything else :)

**EDIT**

Here is a solution of a neater way to implement what I think you have :)

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('div.show').toggleClass('show');
        target = '#'+$(this).data('target');
        $(target).toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yKfaB/

Comment: just curious, what's wrong with jQuery's Show()/Hide() functions?

Comment: I prefer to use it because I can easily toggle and see what styles are applied. It reduces the amount of inline styling and makes the outcome more predictable!

Comment: The update is close, but the asker wanted the current item to toggle. This logic only turns on the current selection. Nice use of `data()` though... is it faster than `attr('data-target')`?